# Molecular orbital diagram of hydroxide ion?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I would like to understand how to create a molecular orbital diagram for the hydroxide ion from scratch. This includes understanding the shape of the molecular orbital.

Here is an attempt I have come up with:
[image]
Where the top MO is sigma* and the bottom is simply sigma.
But this makes no sense. I haven't used up all the available electrons of the oxygen atom, and the diagram seems to suggest that there is a bond order of zero between the two atoms?

However, this goes against my understanding of MOs - surely only two molecular orbitals can be formed from a p orbital and an s orbital (sigma/sigma*) and none others? I couldn't form a pi molecular orbital, for instance.

I think I've made a mistake in that I need O$^{2-}$ instead of O, but even then I don't see how that helps.

Once I can understand that, hopefully I will be able to visualise the HOMO of the OH- ion.

Comment: If you have $x$ atomic orbitals to begin with, they form $x$ molecular orbitals. Two of your MOs are missing. My suggestion is to look up the MO diagram for HF in a textbook (or online). Hydroxide ion is the same as HF, except that you write O instead of F.

Comment: Your scheme has 9 electrons. Nine ! Why ?

Comment: @orthocresol unless we are excluding the oxygen 2s we need five total MOs not four.

Comment: @orthocresol HF's M.O. diagram shows 1s of H at a higher energy level than O's 2p orbitals. Why is that so? I would expect it to be of lower energy and more bound to the nucleus..

Comment: @napstablook HF, or O's 2p orbitals? Anyway, that might look surprising, but it shouldn't be. 1s is indeed lower than 2p, but *only within the same atom*. Oxygen's nucleus has 7 more protons than hydrogen. Fluorine has 8 more.

Comment: @orthocresol In both (hydroxide and fluorine), but I suppose you are right (the specifics are dependent on calculation for higher orbitals anyways). Thanks for the clarification!